# Ruby on Rails test coverage with simplecov

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, automated-tests, simplecov

I want to analyse the test coverage of our code , and therefore, installed the simplecov gem.

Our testing environement has 2 seperate project: REST API test (Java+Rest-Assured) and Web UI testing (Java-Selenium).
As you can see, we dont have unit testing inside the rails app, and we are testing using external projects.


I configured the simplecov gem as descriped in the tutorial and put this, in the rails script:

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails'
puts "require simplecov"
```

When loading the app, I see the string I printed.


I ran both automation test projects, saw their printouts in the rails log, but I don't see **any** coverage of controllers/models, I see only small precentage of initializtion files of some gems and rails.

I searched the net, and tried putting the code phrase in boot.rb or even puma.rb and it returned the same results.

Any ideas?

***EDIT***

Nothing helped with all the comments, but I figured out something very interesting, in all cases, I only see the name of methods marked as tested, not the content (in controllers).
I tried to put the simplecov start phrase in both bin/rails, puma.rb, config.ru, environment.rb, all not given the desired results of code coverage.

Comment: There are a couple of things that might go wrong here. First, you should run puma single-threaded. SimpleCov's multi-threading support is limited. Second, have you tried using SimpleCov's at_exit hook? It will help you find out when and where SimpleCov stop "recording" code execution coverage: https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov#customizing-exit-behaviour .
Third, Ruby's coverage might provide everything you need already, so you don't need SimpleCov in the first place: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/coverage/rdoc/Coverage.html
I hope you find that helpful.

Comment: Our puma is running single threaded, also, what you shared about the ruby lib seems to be as per class, which can be very tough to control

Comment: I dont understand " and we are testing using external projects. "

Comment: @SimonFranzen Tests are not rails unit tests, but using external projects like selenium and rest-assured.

Comment: Then I am not sure, how SimpleCov can track those tests and the coverage.

Comment: @SimonFranzen According to their documentation it's possible, but it's not working for me.

Comment: Well regarding your case that the methods names are hit (green) is typical behavior since the stack gets loaded and simplecov recognizes that the methods are there. But this means they are basically untested. Anyhow whats the "rails script" you are referring to where you put the simplecov starter?

Comment: You definitively have to put it into `bin/rails` after the shebang and before everything else. But also that is the important part: you have to run `bin/rails server` and not just `rails server`. At least this triggered changes in my coverage unfortunately I can't test much further since we have rspec going.

Comment: @DennyMueller I put it on bin/rails in the application directory. I also put some prints there in order to see it when running "rails s", and I do see the puts's.

Comment: @YogevAbr see my second comment.. stupid 5 minute limit on comment edits

Comment: @DennyMueller Get the same, but now I've noticed that I get this message upon terminatin the rails app: Coverage report generated for MiniTest to /Users/... , what is MiniTest? this is not my tests framework, I don't use ROR test frameworks.

Comment: @YogevAbr cant tell you why you get this. maybe you still have the gem in your gemfile. Who knows since we dont know much about your project. But at least you are at the point that simplecov gets correctly initialized. Now you jsut have to fiddle around with the configuration.

Comment: @DennyMueller I am actually at the same starting point, I had the same behavior before posting this question here, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure simplecov can measure the whole rails app coverage... But I googled something that you can attach as a rack middleware:

https://github.com/danmayer/coverband

And it's output is compatible with simplecov. So it looks like it could be useful in your case.

As you mentioned in your question you're using puma. I suspect that, since it's multi-threaded, it spawns a few rails apps and their simplecov output overwrites each other's results. I'd try with the single threaded server like webrick - but this may make your tests slower (depending on how the tests are fired up really) or try the `coverband` gem.

Also - even if the server is single threaded - I'm not sure if each request would not overwrite `simplecov`'s output.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!! Work like a charm! Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to specify the paths

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start do

  # add_filter '/admin/'

  add_group "Models", "app/models"
  add_group "Controllers", "app/controllers"
  add_group "Lib", "lib/"
  add_group "Helpers", "app/helpers"
end
```

Comment: With these paths I get 0/0 (100%) coverage, which is probably wrong.

Comment: @YogevAbr Have you tried using absolute paths, to make sure this isn't an issue about working directory? Like `add_group "Models", "/home/user/path/to/project/app/models"`

Answer (score 0):

You need  to to start SimpleCov before loading any of your files, so put these lines as early as possible in your ruby entrypoint:

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start
```

You could see an example in one of my repos here:
https://github.com/tareksamni/DockUp/blob/master/spec/spec_helper.rb

I do `autoload` my ruby code after starting `SimpleCov`. You need to the same as well:

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start

require './autoload'
```

Comment: I don't have a spec helper, as I don't running any tests using the rails environment, which file is loaded first with rails 5? you know?

Comment: Same results. I really start to think that I am wasting my time and it's a bug with simplecov.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to get coverage for the e2e playwright tests. Meanwhile subprocess handling was added to SimpleCov in 2020, so I created unicorn conf for the CI

```
timeout          60
worker_processes 1
preload_app      true
listen           3000

app_path =  File.expand_path('../', __dir__)    
stderr_path "#{app_path}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"

if ENV['CI']
  require File.expand_path('../lib/tutuf/simplecov', __dir__)
  SimpleCov.command_name 'End-to-End Tests'
  SimpleCov.enable_for_subprocesses true
  SimpleCov.at_fork do |pid|
    # This needs a unique name so it won't be overwritten
    SimpleCov.command_name "#{SimpleCov.command_name} (subprocess: #{pid})"
    SimpleCov.formatter SimpleCov::Formatter::LcovFormatter
    SimpleCov.minimum_coverage 0
    SimpleCov.start
  end
end
```

Then started the unicorn server with

```
bundle exec unicorn_rails --config-file config/unicorn_test.rb --env test --daemonize
```

and ran the tests with

```
npx playwright test e2e --workers=1
```

The coverage is written to the disk on shutting down the server. To be able to post it to codacy, I added to the CI configuration

```
kill -QUIT `cat tmp/pids/unicorn.pid`
while [ -s tmp/pids/unicorn.pid ]; do
    sleep 2
done
```

to give some time to SimpleCov to flush the report to the disk before attempting to send it. Initially I started with wait time of 0.2s but it was insufficient and I increased it to 2s. Depending on the machine you run and the size of the coverage report you may need to increase it further.